# How to pass more parametrers than used in an oracle query in ODP.NET without getting exception?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I just came across this disturbing error. I try to execute a simple sql query, using ODP.NET in c#. I pass parameters by name (setting command's BindByName=true)
The query uses one parameter named "tid".
When I add only this parameter to the command's parameter collection everything is ok.
If I add another parameter, that it is not used in the query, the query crashes with this error message

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

The code looks like this

```
using( var conn = new OracleConnection([some connection string]) )
{
   conn.Open();
   using( var comm = conn.CreateCommand() )
   {
      // using only the :tid parameter.
      comm.CommandText = "SELECT column FROM Table T WHERE T.Id = :tid";

      comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      comm.BindByName = true;

      comm.Parameters.Add("tid", 500000207);

      // This extra parameter causes an exception when the query is executed.
      // If I remove it everything runs smoothly
      comm.Parameters.Add("param2", "ValueOfSecondParam");

      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

**How can I pass more parameters than actually used in the query, without getting an exception?** (Suppose I create the query dynamically but I don't control the parameters to pass so I have to pass all parameters in the first place)

Comment: I don't find this error *disturbing*. If you create the query dynamically, you know which parameters you need. Filter accordingly.

Comment: Why would you want to pass parameters that don't exist in the query?  If you are building the query dynamically, you presumably know when you're building it what parameters you need to pass in.  Why wouldn't you simply use that knowledge to drive which parameters get added to the collection?

Comment: Agreed.  It's throwing an error because your paramater counts / values don't match. If it's dynamic - do it in code.  A piece of advice - moving forward when you see errors - don't try to work around them immediately - try to understand what they mean and why.

Comment: you only have 1 variable to bind, why (try) to pass 2 (unless its a returnvalue, doesn't make sense)

Comment: Hopefully this will help your learning path.  All of us have asked (seemingly at the time) ..less than ideal questions.  That's how we learn.  I'm sure if bill gates read some of my questions..he'd be like "what is wrong with that guy?".  Godspeed with your endeavors

Comment: As I commented to Bob Jarvis' answer, there is the scenario when the command text is built by one part of the code, the parameter collection is provided before hand by another part of the code, and they are both assembled into a command object by a third part of the code, and those three parts have no knowledge of one another. This is a scenario when you can actually provide more parameters than needed. I think it is a legitimate need.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine that instead of supplying parameters to an SQL query you're handing parts to a mechanic who's trying to assemble a car.  Assume that you're playing that part of Bud Abbott, and the database/mechanic is Lou Costello:

```
Abbott:   Alright, Lou, let's get busy putting this car together.  The owner's
          in a big rush.
Costello: Sounds good to me.
Abbott:   Here's the steering wheel.
Costello: Thank you very much.
A:  And here's the engine.
C:  (Ooof!) Oh, thank you SO very much!
A:  And now the first wheel.
C:  That's great.
A:  And now the second wheel.
C:  Looks all nice and shiny with all the chrome, eh?
A:  That's just lovely, Lou.  Oh, here's the third wheel.
C:  I'll just put in back here, behind the driver.
A:  Fine, fine.  And here's the fourth wheel...
C:  Looks great!  I think we're...
A:  And here's the fifth wheel...
C:  Uh, hold on here a minute...
A:  And here's the sixth wheel...
C:  Hang on, Bud, I think we've got a little problem here...
A:  And now the seventh wheel...
C:  Seven wheels?  Seven wheels?!?  WHADDYA MEAN, SEVEN WHEELS!?!?!?
A:  Oh, stop complaining, will you?  Just put it on...
C:  But...
A:  Hurry up now...
C:  But...
A:  ...because here's the eighth wheel.
C:  HEY, ABBBBBOTTTTTTTTTT!!!!!!!
```

So, as you can see, supplying more wheels (or parameters) is not something that makes a lot of sense - although it *could* make for a great comedy routine.  :-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Upvote for the effort taken to provide this answer!  Somewhere there has to be acceptance of "intelligent design".

Comment: There is also the scenario of "I give you a whole bunch of junk beforehand, and you use only what you want". To make it more clear, suppose that the code is written by three parties that don't have access to one another. The first one supplies an array of parameters (let's say environment parameters), the second one supplies a dynamically created command text that may or may not use each parameter (so the first party doesn't know what actually is being used) and the third party collects the text and the parameter array and builds the command object.

Comment: There's also the scenario of "I've written some code to pass in some parameters, and those are critically important parameters used in running, say, a nuclear power plant, and here I am calling a routine which doesn't use all of them - hey, database, take your best shot!".  From the perspective of a software vendor who has NO idea how their product is being used, if something is mis-specified it's evidence that something is wrong in the program and that said program should be notified, and the operation should not be allowed to proceed.  It's better to do no harm than hope for the best...

Comment: Still, using SqlClient (SQL SERVER), I have no problem doing this. It doesn't seem that sql server complains when you provide more parameters.
At the end of the day, my question is whether I can do this or not, and not the reason behind it.
I agree that this is probably an indicator of a wrong desing though.
In this hypothetical scenario those parameters are not critical, and the query functions more or less like a template...

Comment: It appears that the answer is "No, you can't do that.  If you provide unneeded parameters you'll get an ORA-01036 error".

Comment: Costello could say: 'I would use those wheels if you gave me truck SDK! For now I'll throw them away!'